# How to consume multiple message types through one queue with C# and RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, json, rabbitmq

currently I try to implement a MessagingClient, working with RabbitMQ and C#.

My idea is that every service uses its own queue for receiving messages and there is an own exchange for each message type. For example a message type could be "download/requested" or "download/started". These exchanges are of type "fanout". Now the clients, that want to listen on some message, bind their queue to the corresponding exchange. For example the download service binds its queue "download-bot" to the exchange "download/requested".

My problem is now that I can't really imagine, how to deal with different types of messages on the parsing site. I use Newtonsoft.Json for encoding/decoding the message objects. For each different message type, there is separate "handler" I want to execute. This handler should get the message (deserialized) as a parameter. My problem is, that with mulitple message types over one queue, there seems to be just one handler qer queue. How do I find out, which concrete handler to execute and how to parse the message, if I don't know the type at compile time? I know an important keyword will be "reflection", but I could not tinker something working together. I should say that i'm pretty new with C#. Could someone provide a working example of this ? Or is this even something, I should do like that?

As a workarround, currently I got the following (reduced) example (using one queue per message type and service)

```
namespace Lib.Message {
public class RabbitMqMessageClient : IMessageClient {

    private static NLog.ILogger logger = Common.Logger.GetLogger ();
    private RabbitMqConfig config;
    private IModel model;

    private const string DOWNLOAD_REQUESTED = "download/requested";

    public RabbitMqMessageClient (RabbitMqConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory () { HostName = config.Hostname };
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection ();
        this.model = connection.CreateModel ();
    }

    public Task PublishDownloadRequested (string userRef, string id, string url) {
        var message = new DownloadRequestMessage (userRef, id, url);
        return this.publish (DOWNLOAD_REQUESTED, message);
    }
    public Task SubscribeToDownloadRequested (Action<DownloadRequestMessage> action) {
        return this.subscribe<DownloadRequestMessage> (DOWNLOAD_REQUESTED, action);
    }
    public Task SubscribeToDownloadRequested (Func<DownloadRequestMessage, Task> action) {
        return this.subscribe<DownloadRequestMessage> (DOWNLOAD_REQUESTED, action);
    }

    public Task Start () {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task subscribe<TPayloadType> (string topic, Action<TPayloadType> action) {
        Func<TPayloadType, Task> wrappedAction = (TPayloadType args) => {
            action (args);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        return this.subscribe<TPayloadType> (topic, wrappedAction);
    }

    private Task subscribe<TPayloadType> (string topic, Func<TPayloadType, Task> action) {
        var queue = $"{config.QueueName}--{topic}";

        model.ExchangeDeclare (topic, ExchangeType.Fanout, true);

        model.QueueDeclare (
            queue,
            durable : true,
            exclusive : false,
            autoDelete : false,
            arguments : null);

        model.QueueBind (config.QueueName, topic, "foo");

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer (model);
        // this consumer will be shared for multiple queues right ?
        // maybe even not here in this method, but in the "Start" method
        consumer.Received += async (model, ea) => {
            logger.Info ($"handling {ea.Exchange}");

            var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (ea.Body.Span.ToArray ());
            // here I need to know how to deserialize the payload from the value of "ea.Exchange"
            var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TPayloadType>(jsonString);
            // I think i have to put the action in a map (?) instead and then find the concrete handler by the exchange name? 
            await action(message);
        };

        model.BasicConsume (config.QueueName, true, consumer);


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task publish (string topic, object payload) {
        logger.Info ($"publishing {topic}");

        string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (payload);
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (message);

        model.BasicPublish (
            exchange: topic,
            routingKey: "foo",
            basicProperties : null,
            body : bytes
        );

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you cannot/don't want to use multiple queues, a common approach is to have an EventName (or similar) property in all messages, json-parse it and then json-deserialize to that known type (you'll need a dictionary/switch to map string -> class|handler).

Comment: First, thanks for your quick reply. I already tried to have a private member "handlers" of type "IDictionary<string, Func<object, Task>", but I struggled to Add a value of type "Func<DownloadRequestMessage, Task>" to the dictionary, because I could not simply cast it to the more generic Func<object, Task>. Do you have advises how to do that ?

Comment: You have at least 2 ways: the casting approach (interface and a method that takes `object` and casts) and the switch approach (`switch x { case y: await Y.Run(...); ...`) where the methods accept the concrete type.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel and there's really no need to. People already resolved these issues and we have great frameworks like MassTransit or Rebus.FM. Both are great, I work with both for years and personally recommend both. Both are well documented and you should be able to start quickly.